# Why does ImageView Image Zoomed when ScrollView added?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I want to scroll my Card View but when i have added the ScrollView my Image in ImageView is get zoomed/stretched. Following screenshots represents my issue.

[ImageView before adding ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACTxB.png)

[ImageView after adding Scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPNR.png)

**My Activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OrbitPostViewer">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/orbitPostSharedImg"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/rabindranath_tagore"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

As shown in above code. I have also added fillViewport to true, still it's not working. CardView works fine when i remove the scroll view but i am not able to scroll.

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: is that the actual image size?

Comment: Image size is 1071 x 1500 pixels. But different size images also behaves the same on Image View.

Answer (score 1):

change ImageView scaleType from `centerCrop` to `centerInside`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:layout_gravity="center"` for the linear layout that contains imageview and change scale type to `centerInside` or `fitCenter`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/orbitPostSharedImg"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/rabindranath_tagore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```